# Spring Security - two separate sources for authentication information

Tags: java, spring-security

My Spring Security form-based login currently contains a form and the default LdapAuthenticationProvider and I am able to authenticate properly.
But there's a new requirement to check that user is enabled. This information is in database instead of LDAP. So how do I do this?

Should I be looking at using the AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter and performing the extra check in the successfulAuthentication method

Or is there a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that extending the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and overriding `attemptAuthentication()` is a good way. In `attemptAuthentication()` you can check both DB data and LDAP data. You can load user info using the `UserDetailsService` like [this](http://www.codercorp.com/blog/spring/security-spring/writing-custom-userdetailsservice-for-spring-security.html).

Another way is (as you suggested yourself) extending the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and running your filter after the FORM_LOGIN filter like this:

```
<http ...>
    ...
    <custom-filter after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthenticationProcessingFilter" />
</http>
```

A good idea probably is to make 2 separate filters for LDAP and DB authentication and running one after the other. This way you can turn any of them off if you need to.

[This](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#filter-stack) part of the spring docs will help you on custom filters.